# Unable to install ggplot2 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: r, ggplot2, ubuntu-11.10

I am getting the following error when trying to install ggplot2:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/dodo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need R (>= 2.14.0) for this version.

So please go and see the [instructions at CRAN to upgrade on Ubuntu to the current R](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu) and once you have R 2.14.2 up and running (which is a matter of four or five commands, thanks to the magic of apt-get and friends, upgrade to the current ggplot2.

Comment: +1 thanks Dirk. Particularly interesting to people using RStudio Server!

Comment: +1 amazing, it solved my issue with RStudio Server and ggplot2 on Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[ggplot2-0.9.0](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) has an explicit dependency on R >= 2.14 (and an implicit one of R >= 2.14.1). Thus it can not be installed in R version 2.13.1. Perhaps you can get the previous version (0.8.9) from the archives and install that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a version that is appropriate to your old version of R or you need to upgrade. To go the first route, you should find a version of ggplot2 in the Archives and then install from source (which is I believe the default for Linux). Perhaps try the UCLA CRAN mirror:

http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_0.8.9.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks, this helped with the command:"R CMD INSTALL ggplot2_0.8.9.tar.gz"